# mysql trigger para replicar o valor do ID noutra coluna

Tags: mysql

Tenho andado em torno disto mas o valor é "NULL"

```
create trigger tr_ReplID before insert on DuploId FOR EACH ROW set new.ID=new.Replica_ID;
```

O que pretendo...
Ao inserir dados na tabela Processos o **ID** será o número do processo, posteriormente ao fazer alterações na tabela com formulário PHP o número do processo que será mostrado será o **Replica_ID**, que poderá ser duplicado e assim saber sempre que estou a alterar o processo pretendido. Na minha ignorância é a forma de o fazer ...
Será que me podem ajudar?
Obrigado

Answer (score 0):

Depois alguns testes cheguei à conclusão que talvez não seja possível copiar o ID. (pelo menos com trigger simples) 
Estarei correcto?
Fiz um teste com um trigger que copia e Formata a Data e funciona, com o ID NULL ou "0".

PS: uso MariaDB em Linux